# Petición AJAX a un Httpmodule

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, cordova, http

Tengo dos proyectos. Por un lado tengo una aplicación basada en Apache Cordova desde la cual quiero realizar una petición AJAX a un httpmodule que he creado en otra aplicación web paralela.

Soy incapaz de acceder al módulo creado en la aplicación web. Lo he realizado tanto mediante jQuery como con POSTMAN. A continuación os dejo el código y los ejemplos que he realizado.

En el siguiente fragmento de código, al hacer click sobre el botón login compruebo que existe el usuario en mi base de datos local y realizo la petición al proyecto dónde tengo alojado el módulo.

```js
$("body").on('click', '#loginButton', function () {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT count (*) as cnt FROM Users WHERE UserName = "' + $('#UserName').val() + '" and PasswordHash = "' + $.md5($('#password').val()) +'"', [], function (tx, rsp) {
                if (rsp.rows.item(0) != null && rsp.rows.item(0).cnt > 0) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: "http://localhost:12665",
                        processData: true,
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        headers: {
                            "accept": "application/jsonp",
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                        },
                        data: {},
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log("Funcionando")
                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            console.log("No funciona")
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $("#errorLogin").removeClass("d-none")
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

Por otro lado, en la aplicación web donde tengo alojado el módulo tengo el siguiente código para definirlo.

```
    public class Authentication : IHttpModule
{
    void IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.AuthenticateRequest += new EventHandler(this.OnAuthenticateRequest);
    }

    void OnAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void IHttpModule.Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

Junto con la siguiente configuración del web.config.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="Authentication" type="APPModule.Authentication"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

El objetivo de crear el módulo es ejercer de una capa intermedia entre la aplicación basada en apache cordova y un servidor con una autenticación concreta que no se puede realizar desde jQuery.

Lo que realmente no se, es si la mejor opción es utilizar la alternativa de httpmodule o existe alguna otra opción que no he contemplado.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Y un servicio REST/SOAP en vez de HttpModule? De esa manera simplemente harías un POST/GET que recibiese la información para validarse, y devolverías una respuesta afirmativa o un error.

Comment: Lo que realmente quiero es realizar una especie de "proxy" que según la acción que se realice en la aplicación movil, esta capa intermedia tome uno u otro camino en mi servidor.

Comment: Creo que eso es indiferente para la elección entre HttpModule y un servicio web. La lógica del flujo puede estar en la web y, conforme el usuario haga una cosa o la otra, consultar la información de uno u otro endpoint del servicio.

Comment: Otra cosa, que no conozco Apache Cordova, pero no es una muy buena práctica el tener acceso a base de datos desde el cliente (Javascript), ni hacer SELECTs ahí a pelo.

Comment: Voy a probar lo que dices con el web service y ya te diré como queda el asunto. En cuanto a la base de datos, es una pequeña base de datos local en mysqli la cual se tiene que validar sobre el servidor, es una pequeña validación previa, que posteriormente lo valido contra mi servidor. En ningún momento el usuario desde el movil podrá ver el código js.

Comment: Okas, seguro que encontrás los servicios web mucho más sencillos de utilizar. Y lo de la base de datos, simplemente era un comentario, :)

Comment: Muchas gracias!